# ExportAsFixedFormat for VBA saving Files

Tags: vba, ms-word, file-conversion, pdf-conversion

i have a problem regarding the process of saving a bunch of pdfs (exported from WordDocuments).
The runtime of my program just behaves a bit weird and thats why i am asking.
So I want to save the files on a global drive.
In my program i create a folder (in that drive where) i put all the pdfs.

Somehow if i do this operation for the first time it is really slow.

But if I do this operation ( for the same fodler a second time) it is somehow really fast. (after I deleted the "old" pdfs, or the old pdfs where overwritten)

I am a bit frustrated and I cannot explain why that is

Could somebody help pls
Would be very happy for an answer

Greetings
Jonas

Using this simple code

```
doc.ExportAsFixedFormat wholefile, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
```

Comment: Since your problem looks to be the folder creation, it is at least strange to not showing us the respective code. Then, what do you mean by "a global drive"? Did you try the creation part in a separate `Sub`. How long does it take?

Comment: Hey first of all thank you for the reply. @FaneDuru The global drive I mean is the drive of my company I am working. And i am pretty sure that there is nothing wrong about the folder creation ( which i did in a seperate sub) because the folder creation always works perfectly fine (just did it with MkDir). Also @K J thanks for the response. I do not really know much about caches so is there something that i can do to kind of "prepare " the folder ( when creating them in diff sub) in order to accelerate the runtime when saving the files - Thanks again in advance

Comment: What is the file path passed to the method? Is it a local drive?

Comment: Thanks for the response @EugeneAstafiev the file is also in the folder of the workbook (that is on the global drive)

Comment: What happens if you try this on a local drive?

Comment: Have you tried to specify the file format as XPS instead of PDF?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple reasons why the [ExportAsFixedFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.exportasfixedformat) method can be slow. But I would start from dealing with local files only. Then I'd play with arguments specifying the document quality and exported format. It makes sense to play with other parameters left in your code sample to its default values.